# Grails clean-all - it is saying cannot delete few plugins

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am getting problems while doing complete clean(clean-all), even while deleting 'target' folder from folder explorer or from eclipse IDE also

It is not deleting few plugins.

please help me...

Answer (score 1):

the script cannot delete the files on disk to to permission given or the files are still open by some java process. Close the Eclipse, delete the plugin folders or the whole `~/.grails/[version]/[your project]` dir